# Help identify outdoor frost free faucet make & model

Tags: faucet, frost, outdoorfaucet

My other outdoor frost-free faucet is a Mansfield 4000 series, but I have a difficult time trying to identify this other one.

[image: frost-free faucet]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's a different make/model? Does a close up inspection of the part reveal any mfgr/model info? _Why_ do you need to know, simple curiosity? Repair parts?

Comment: Either there are no markings or they have eroded. The overall construction looks visibly different from the other one, which I just posted a question about (https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/195440/104944). This document (https://www.prier.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/mansfield-stem.pdf) is how I determined that one's make & model. It's for future repair needs and for now mostly curiosity. I'm actually trying to fix the Mansfield. I dissembled this one trying to get some ideas but realized the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/7HwiaP2VO5M), this is likely some model of [B&K Mueller](https://www.completeplumbingsource.com/bk-mueller-repair-parts) QuarterMaster hydrants.

[image: B&K Muller]